# How to disable a magento extension from admin?

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions

My site has an extension called "**instantsearch+**" for product searching operation. I want to disable it and use the default magento search. I have selected option "*NO*" for "Enable *InstantSearch+*" in the admin section, But still it is working as before.
Kindly suggest how to disable it and use the **default magento search option** ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to set it to `no` on all scopes in System > Configuration.

Also, to disable it on the frontend you can use the fields in `System > Configuration > Advanced`, find your module and set it to `Disable`

But the best way to disable a module is to go to the directory `app/etc/modules` with FTP and look for the XML file belonging to that module and change `<active>true</active>` to `<active>false</active>`

And as always, don't forget to flush all the caches and recompile if you're using the compiler

Comment: Thanks @Sander Mangel . Though the first two methods didn't work but I managed it in the third. i.e. updating the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to disable it in **app/etc/modules/instasearch.xml** (or the relevent name for that module xml)  and in tag  replace true by **false**